# Ubuntu переход в сон при закрытии крышки ноутбука

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня есть ноутбук к нему подключен монитор. Когда подключен монитор ноутбук не переходит в сон при закрытии крышки, когда монитора нет переходит в сон при закрытии крышки. Как сделать так чтоб переходил в сон в обоих вариантах?
p.s. Ubuntu 18.04